# Phonegap Build - Crossplatform BarcodeScanner integration

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I'm developing a crossplatform application in HTML5/CSS/JS using Phonegap 5.1.1. I'm struggling to find a solution to integrate the official `phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`, following the instructions which the [official page](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner) on GitHub refers to. In detail, after building through [Phonegap Build](http://build.phonegap.com), I can't get rid of the Help page which appears as soon as I start the app on Android (see the [image: attached image]). This way I cannot test if everything's working fine.

Furthermore, I've found out there are loads of ways to initialize the plugin and I'd like to know whether I'm doing anything wrong. Here's the code in my page:

```
var scanner = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner");

scanner.scan(
    function (result) {
    alert("We got a barcode\n" +
          "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
          "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
          "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
    }, 
    function (error) {
        alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
    });
```

Finally, I've modified my config.xml as to include:
    `<gap:plugin name="BarcodeScanner"/>`

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, you are bar code-scanner plugin add using manually or using CLI..?

Comment: I'm using CLI, adding the plugin through the cmd 'phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. In case anyone is looking for a ready-to-use way to start, here's the way to go.

If you're using Phonegap Build online service, you need not add any plugin via
    `phonegap plugin add <plugin_name>` (or `cordova plugin add`). It'll be sufficient to simply mimic the behavior of the official [Phonegap BarcodeScanner Demo](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeDemo), particularly as regards the files:

- `<appname>/config.xml` (referencing the plugin `com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner`);
- `<appname>/index.html` (which includes the line `<script src="barcodescanner.js" />`);
- `<appname>/js/index.js` (which contains the `scan` and `encode` methods, as well as their initialization).

As soon as the app is built, Phonegap Build will inject the official plugin by itself within the package.

Answer (score 0):

please add bellow permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
```

Comment: Ok, I've added those to my AndroidManifest.xml, yet that doesn't seem to be working (I've also deleted `<preference name="permissions" value="none" />` from config.xml).